# Redshift COPY error 1206 invalid timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-redshift, date-formatting

I am trying to use the COPY command to move some data into redshift, however it does not like the format of the timestamp value.  In the dataset it is formatted as MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI

```
copy table_name from '[data source]'
access_key_id '[access key]'
secret_access_key '[secret access key]'
region 'us-east-1'
dateformat 'auto'
null as 'NA'
delimiter ','
removequotes;
```

I tried using dateformat 'auto' to detect the format, however it still gives me the same error code and says:

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

I also tried

```
dateformat as 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24/MI'
```

However, it also came cack with error code 1206.

Does anyone know how to fix this to where it will accept the timestamp format that is already set in the data?

Answer (score 2):

Using both

```
dateformat as 'auto'
timeformat as 'auto'
```

together, they seem to work, uploading all the data, just altering the format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1):

You should try `timeformat 'auto'` instead of `dateformat 'auto'`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/automatic-recognition.html

Comment: Tried this and now I get error code 1205 on the next column of type date formatted as MM/DD/YYYY and it says invalid digit encountered.  the date was 11/18/2011